# Excel copying and pasting wrong data

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks with the same data in them. I accidentally deleted a column from the file so I want to copy the data from a backup.

In SOURCE (my backup), the value of the first 24 cells that have data in column [Event\Work Type], are "Wedding" and after that is a value "TWO FAMILY..."

When I copy this column and go to paste it to DESTINATION, the copy seemed to have left out cells and it only pastes TEN values of "Wedding," which of course offsets the rows and is now missing data.

I tried different ways like using the "special\consistant" but there you can clearly see that data is missing and not getting copied.

There ARE some hidden rows, but they are the same hidden rows in both files.

Below is some screenshot. I'd appreciate suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the filters from both worksheets, then copy your data.

Comment: The filters are the same on both files so even though there are hidden rows, they are the same hidden rows on both files.

Comment: Have you TRIED clearing the filters?

Comment: Although this makes thousands of rows more, it didn't take longer to paste and this worked! Make this comment and answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the filters from both worksheets, then copy your data.

Copying and pasting values from / to filtered ranges can yield unexpected results...